# Image Centering Issue Inside Parent Div Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used JavaScript to create a slideshow on the homepage of my site. The problem I'm having is that the image will not center to the page, despite my best efforts. I can get it centered if I set the image child element like so:

```
#slider img {
    left: 218px;}
```

but that doesn't center for different window sizes. I'm using fairly large images, but they can always be resized later. I used placeholders for the fiddle. How can you fix this?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7j7gtok2/3/)

Comment: can we see html part of your work?

Comment: It's in the JSFiddle link I put at the bottom of the description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U can easily center image by set up:

```
#slider img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%; // or your own width
}
```

Comment: But only for 100% width... anything less off-centers the image again.

Comment: No problem.. remember for responsiveness u have to use `percentage`

Answer (score 1):

Your images inside `#slider` have a `position: absolute`. This negates the scope of the container and the image is no longer relatively positioned inside the container `div#slider`.

Use `margin: auto` and `display: block` **without** absolute positioning.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/sukritchhabra/smndp65m/

Comment: I use absolute positioning because the JavaScript code I have lists the images one after another vertically. The first image fades out, then the second one fades in underneath it, all the way down the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div align='center'>Hello world</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do `margin:auto`.

Comment: Also doesn't work. :( I feel like I've tried everything.

Comment: @Aaron what doesn't work about it? What do you want to change that both of those answers aren't doing?

Comment: When u centering object with `margin` u have to include `display: block;` or it will not gonna work..

Comment: @stephenpassero The image is stuck on the right half of the page, I want it to be centered horizontally.

Comment: @LiborZahrádka, That moved the images to the left.

Comment: @Aaron you might have to do `display:block;` or `display:inline-block;`.

Comment: @Aaron try `display:inline-block;`

Comment: @stephenpassero check out my answer please, if u wanna to resize element with size of browser u have to use percentage of the page like `width: 100%` etc...